# Ratio and divisibility

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Given that $5x=3y=z$ where $x, y, z$ are integers, each choice given
>   below must be integer except?
>
> A) $z/15 \quad\quad $ B) $z/5 \quad\quad$  C) $z/3 \quad\quad\\ $ D)
>   $z/xy \quad\quad\\$  E) $x/3$

(Ans=D)

How would I solve this problem any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to solve this type of problem is to plug some numbers in, and try to get a feel for WHY the various expressions either have to be integers, or don't have to be.  It shouldn't take very long to discover that $x$ must be a multiple of 3, $y$ must be a multiple of 5, and that we can write $x=3w$, $y=5w$ and $z=15w$ for some integer $w$.

Since this is clearly a question in a quick-fire multiple choice test, a rigorous proof is unlikely to be needed.  In fact, we've already done enough to show that A, B, C and E are not the correct answers.  So circle D and move on to the next question.  If "none of the above" had been one of the options, then keep going - eventually you'll try $w=2$, and discover that D is indeed correct.

Answer (score 1):

Why $15$ divides $z$ (meaning that $z/15$ is an integer): If a prime, in this case $3$, divides a product, in this case $5x$, then the prime must divide one (or both) of the terms. Since $3$ does not divide $5$, we conclude that $3$ must divide $x$.

So $x=3t$ for some $t$, and therefore $x=15t$. We conclude that $15$ divides $z$.

The same kind of reasoning (but easier) shows that $z/5$, $z/3$, and $x/3$ are integers. In fact, we have already shown all these things in the process of showing that $15$ divides $z$. So by a process of elimination, the right answer must be D).

But we can see separately that $z/(xy)$ is *not necessarily* an integer. For example, let $x=6$, $y=10$, and $z=30$. Then your conditions are met, but $xy$, which is $60$, does not divide $z$.

Note that $z/(xy)$ *can* be an integer, if $x=3$ and $y=5$. These are in fact the only positive cases when under our conditions, $z/(xy)$ is an integer.

Comment: I can see z is divisible by all other options however for $\frac{z}{xy}$ I am assuming $x = 3 \times 5 $ and $y=5 \times 3$ it is also divisible . Am I wrong ?

Comment: If $x=3\times 5$ and $y=5\times 3$, then it is not true that $5x=3y$. I think you meant $x=3$, $y=5$. That certainly **is** a possibility, and then $z/xy$ **is** an integer. But there are other possibilities for $x$ and $y$, like the $6$ and $10$ I mentioned. With those, and $z=30$, it will be true that $5x=3y=z$. But for that choice of $x$ and $y$, the number $z/(xy)$ is $30/60$, which is not an integer. So it is not true that $z/(xy)$ **must** be an integer. (But it **can** be.)

Answer (score 0):

We have $5x=3y$, or $x \div y = 3\div 5$

Let their greatest common divisor be $k$, where $k$ is constant ;

So $x=3k$, $y=5k$,
we have $z=5x=5*3k=15k$;
so $z/xy =15k/(3k*5k)=1/k$;
and $1/k < 1$, as $k$ is constant
$1/k$ is not an integer

follow the same style for other options and you will found the answers are integer,

Thus and (d) $z/xy$ is correct;